# Would a dataverse tag be welcome?

Tags: discussion

Some of us who work on the Dataverse project ( https://dataverse.org ) just had a [meeting](https://docs.google.com/document/d/16QePhswhnZNzK0jaAzhFqJkfD-hPwhL0QM26zhB6zcE/edit?usp=sharing) to discuss how to encourage our community to ask questions, answer questions, and build a knowledge base surrounding our software, which **is an open source web application for sharing, citing, analyzing, and preserving research data**.

With a focus on "developers and researchers interested in open data" http://opendata.stackexchange.com seems it might be a good fit for our community, which we believe is already familiar with a variety of Stack Exchange sites.

Specifically, I'm wondering if people on this site would object to a "dataverse" tag that we would encourage our community to use whenever they have questions specific to our software. This would be verify similar to the "android" tag on Stack Overflow. At http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2009/12/hello-stack-overflow.html Roman Nurik from Android Developer Relations wrote:

> In essence, the Android tag on Stack Overflow will become an official Android app development Q&A medium.

A "dataverse" tag might be mutually beneficial if our users come for the tag but stay to ask and answer other Open Data questions.

Comment: I have no complaints ... if you create it, and it's not used, we can always clean it up later.

Comment: was this created and cleaned up later?

Comment: @albert as far as I know, it was never created. Why do you ask? :)

Comment: comment above mine

Comment: @albert you're a man of few words. :) I never did create a "dataverse" tag and I just did a search and only found a few questions with Dataverse in the answer, not the question, so I don't think a tag is warranted. I did go ahead and leave a comment on one of the answers just now. I'm trying to keep an eye on Stack Exchange here and there. Thanks for your interest.

Comment: @PhilipDurbin i've gone from creating unwarranted tags prematurely, to holding out until the need is created organically in my time on the stacks. i believe this to be the best path forward; was looking for historical context proving/disproving/something else to see if this approach was correct/incorrect/could be improved.

Answer (score 1):

The dataverse project is about making data open, so I think it's a great fit.

Comment: tags should be created when there is a need, ideally when there are already multiple questions that can be clumped into it.